# Can not clear rewrite rule in subfolder

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, iis-8

I have this rule in web.config in the root of website which redirects to HTTPS:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

In a subfolder I have separate Config file and I want to clear redirectiong to HTTPS but this folder also redirects to HTTPS:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Rules can be stored defined in web.config only. You can have them there or provided a path to the file where the rules are stored (but it's still defined in the web.config) like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules configSource="App_Config\RewriteRules.config" />
        <outboundRules configSource="App_Config\OutboundRewriteRules.config" />
        <rewriteMaps configSource="App_Config\RewriteMaps.config" />
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If you want certain URLs not to be redirected to HTTPS then you need to create a smart rule which will detect this (or have set of rules).

Comment: Thanks, I had a forward slash instead of a backslash.